# Notebook CPU overheating

Tags: laptop, cpu, overheating

I got an 'old' notebook that is overheating exceeding the CPU's Tjunction. It's a Samsung RV411 using an [i5 m480](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/br/pt/ark/products/52952/intel-core-i5-480m-processor-3m-cache-2-66-ghz.html) CPU, the measured temperature is between 102ºC and 105ºC. I thougt it could be the cooler, so I replaced it but it still the same. The heatsink is working normally and the thermal grease is new, so I decided to try another CPU. I replaced with the [P6100](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/br/pt/ark/products/50175/intel-pentium-processor-p6100-3m-cache-2-00-ghz.html) but the problem continued with the temperature exceeding the P6100 Tjunction with values above 90ºC.

I have no ideas of what to do next. Help me please.

Comment: tJunction on the i5 CPU is 105 (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52952/intel-core-i5-480m-processor-3m-cache-2-66-ghz.html). What OS? I can't speak for Windows but when I had a first gen i5 CPU, I underclocked it so it would save power and run fanless (it was set up as a router). It ran much cooler - so maybe the problem is the driver/performance governor or workload?

Comment: It can be, its good to check the power supply while the temperature is a lot. This means check the voltage and current over the MCU. Its possible the fan paths are blocked, or that the heatsink looks ok, but its not. The temperature is not taken out, because the device receives too much power or the heat is not taken away. Try disabling the speed step in the BIOS.

Comment: Is the CPU thermal grease/pad solidly caked and dried out? Clean it out and replace the thermal grease. Is there a fan? Does it spin? Is it spinning at at the correct rpm or in need of replacement? Maybe the problem is software. Did you format? Can we assume that there is 0% cpu usage and it is hitting 90ºC or is there a rogue program hogging up your cpu?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I've checked the drivers and it seens okay. I've checked the cooling system (heatsink, grease and cooler) all okay. Cooler in BIOS is set to normal (options are normal and low), CPU is set to power-saving in BIOS and Windows. Screen brightness is set to lowest. I runned the HWMonitor and it seens it gets overheated when workload is above about 50%. Check it out https://i.imgur.com/Q5FYAJv.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many months, it seems to be solved by changing the cooler mode in BIOS from normal to low. Weird.

[HWMonitor metering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkwAX.png)